# Error con Volley: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.android.volley.Request

Tags: android-studio, webservice, android-volley

Estoy trabajando con una aplicación que debe conectar con servicios web para poder consultar información de una BD remota, pero al momento de que presiono un botón para lanzar mi servicio web me da el siguiente error:

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.android.volley.Request
>   com.android.volley.RequestQueue.add(com.android.volley.Request)' on a
>   null object reference

No se porque da este error, cuando mi aplicación inicia carga un servicio web que inicia sin problemas pero al usar el botón para lanzar el siguiente servicio web es donde marca el error, esta es la clase donde estoy conectándome con mi Base de datos:

```
public class noticiasWebService implements Response.Listener<JSONObject>, Response.ErrorListener {

    RequestQueue request;
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest;

    public void update(String tituloNoticia, String subtituloNoticia, String imagenNoticia, String descripcionNoticia) {

        String url = "http://192.168.1.72:80/webservicemgrex/agregarFavoritos.php?tituloFavorito="+tituloNoticia+"" +
                "&subtituloFavorito="+subtituloNoticia+
                "&imagenFavorito="+imagenNoticia+
                "&descripcionFavoritos="+descripcionNoticia;

        url = url.replace(" ","%20");
        jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,url,null,this,this);
        request.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        Log.i("Error","Se haregistrado con exito: "+response);
    }

    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Log.i("Error","No se pudo consultar el registro: "+error.toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que sucede es que es has declarado tu `RequestQueue` pero no lo has instanciado la clase de Volley, tucodigo quedaria asi:

```
public class noticiasWebService implements Response.Listener<JSONObject>, Response.ErrorListener {

    RequestQueue request;
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest;

    public void update(String tituloNoticia, String subtituloNoticia, String imagenNoticia, String descripcionNoticia, Context context) {

        String url = "http://192.168.1.72:80/webservicemgrex/agregarFavoritos.php?tituloFavorito="+tituloNoticia+"" +
                "&subtituloFavorito="+subtituloNoticia+
                "&imagenFavorito="+imagenNoticia+
                "&descripcionFavoritos="+descripcionNoticia;

        url = url.replace(" ","%20");
        request = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
        jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,url,null,this,this);
        request.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        Log.i("Error","Se haregistrado con exito: "+response);
    }

    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Log.i("Error","No se pudo consultar el registro: "+error.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, ya hice el cambio que me comentaste pero ahora me da otro error:

Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference

Comment: estas en un activity? o en una clase que has creado?

Comment: es una clase que he creado de echo le agrege un extends AppCompatActivity pero me marca otro error que es este:

Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.File android.content.Context.getCacheDir()' on a null object reference

Comment: he editado mi respuesta, cuando invoque el metodo al presionar el boton tienes que enviarle el contexto puede ser con `update(tituloNoticia,subtituloNoticia,imagenNoticia,descripcionNoticia, getApplicationContext())`

Comment: Tienes razon, muchas gracias por tu ayuda, solamente envie el contexto desde la clase donde invoco el metodo y funciono, muchas gracias.

Comment: de nada,gracias a ti